# Topology optimization issue (or not an issue, which is the issue)

Tags: dynamics, vibration, frequency-response

I am currently doing some work in topology optimization regarding optimizing for the dynamic compliance of a beam structure but I am running into some issues. Well actually I am not running into some issues which is the issue.

So I have this initial uniform domain:

[image: Initial uniform structure]

with the following Dynamic compliance plot (Basically FRF scaled by applied force):

[image: Initial uniform structure FRF]

As is visible, this structure has a resonance at just above 1800Hz and an antiresonance at around 5000Hz.

Now according to this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2018.12.030. I should not be able to get results when raising the excitation frequency above the initial resonance frequency of 1800 Hz, because it will find the antiresonance and kind of 'get stuck' inside this valley. This will of course result in the lowest objective value and it will converge without supplying an actual feasible structure.

However, when I crank up the excitation to 3000Hz, I get this:

[image: Optimization 3000Hz]

with the following FRF:

[image: Optimization 3000Hz FRF]

And cranking it up (6000Hz) even beyond the first anti-resonance I get:

[image: Optimization 6000Hz]

With FRF:

[image: Optimization 6000Hz FRF]

Which are both perfectly feasible designs and I am not sure how this is working.

What I can see however is that my initial anti-resonance at 5000Hz is not moving at al, even for a completely different topology. In the paper above, the excitation frequency and anti-resonance coincide, which creates the proposed issue, but that is not happening for me. Where might this issue lie? I have also recreated the situation from the paper with exactly the same parameters but my anti-resonance does not appear to move. Is it my FEM? Or my optimizer? Any input is very welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did not find 1800 Hz in the paper. Didn't you mean 180 Hz?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about that paper. You've got a method that works.

Comment: Maybe I did not specifiy it clearly but the results I am showing here are with the parameters I intend to use. I did however also recreate the model from the paper but I did not have those results on hand.

Comment: I do however question whether I as a student am suddenly right or someone with a PHD, a lot of published papers, and even using the fortran version of MMA made by Svanberg himself is suddenly wrong

Comment: And I still do not understand why my first anti-resonance is barely moving